# Phantom Wallet Recovery with Password

Tags: wallet, phantom

I was wondering if it was possible to recover wallet access in Phantom with only the password? I created the wallet two years ago and haven't checked it since then. It appears that I did not write down the seed phrases (or misplaced it) but only the wallet password. (I know this is idiotic.) When I try the phantom extension on Chrome, it's asking me to import a wallet or start a new one and it's not just asking for a password. I can see all the ldb files in the chrome app folder but the date on them is from 2024. There are a few text files from 2022 but nothing useful in them. Is there any way to regain access to the wallet? This is the same PC and same Chrome with the same Phantom extension, none of that is new. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without the seed phrases or the private key, it's highly unlikely that you can recover access to your wallet solely with the password. The password alone is not sufficient for wallet recovery in Phantom or any other wallet service. The seed phrases or private key serve as the primary means of recovery and authentication.

Since you've checked the Chrome app folder and found only the ldb files with a recent date and some text files from 2022 without useful information, it seems that you may not have backed up the seed phrases or private key properly.

However, it might still be worth reaching out to the Phantom support team or browsing their documentation for any possible solutions or guidance on wallet recovery.

In the future, it's crucial to securely store your seed phrases or private keys in multiple locations, preferably offline, to prevent such situations. Losing access to your wallet can result in irreversible loss of funds, so it's essential to take proper precautions.